# Error parsing XML: XML InputStream(13) need whitespace between attributes

Tags: java, xml, hibernate

I am new to Hibernate. I have an exception in my Hibernate project, I think it due to my Lecteurs.hbm.xml file.

I need your help please.
thanks.

The exception is as follows:

```
958 [main] ERROR org.hibernate.util.XMLHelper - Error parsing XML: XML InputStream(13) need whitespace between attributes
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document  from resource bean/Lecteurs.hbm.xml
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at util.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:21)
at manager.LecteursManager.ajouterLecteur(LecteursManager.java:13)
at test.Test_Main.main(Test_Main.java:18)
Caused by: org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from resource bean/Lecteurs.hbm.xml
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addResource(Configuration.java:616)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseMappingElement(Configuration.java:1635)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1603)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1582)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1556)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1476)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1462)
at util.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:15)
... 2 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from input stream
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addInputStream(Configuration.java:555)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addResource(Configuration.java:613)
... 9 more
Caused by: org.dom4j.DocumentException: Error on line 13 of document  : need whitespace between attributes Nested exception: need whitespace between attributes
at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:482)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addInputStream(Configuration.java:546)
... 10 more
```

Below is the mappings file Lecteurs.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

 <hibernate-mapping >
      <class name="bean.Lecteurs" table="LECTEURS">
          <id name="id" type="int" column="ID" >
            <generator class="increment"/>           
          </id>

          <property name="nom_lecteur" type="string" column="nomLecteur" />
          <property name="prenom_lecteur"" type="string" column="prenomLecteur" />
          <property name="date_naissance" type="Date" column="dateNaissance" />
          <property name="email_lecteur" column="emailLecteur" ></property>
        <property name="telephone" column="telephoneLecteur" ></property>
        <property name="adresse" column="adresseLecteur" ></property>

    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>﻿
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a two double quotes in a row in this line which could cause that error:

```
<property name="prenom_lecteur"" type="string" column="prenomLecteur" />
```